# What is the UMPU test for a difference in means with unequal variances under an interval null hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Consider two-sample data $x_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta_1, \sigma_1^2)$, $x_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta_2, \sigma_2^2)$ and testing the null hypothesis:
\begin{align*}
H_0: \theta_1 - \theta_2 \in [\theta_l, \theta_u]
\end{align*}
vs the alternative:
\begin{align*}
H_A: \theta_1 - \theta_2 \notin [\theta_l, \theta_u]
\end{align*}

Is there a UMPU test for this null hypothesis?

I know that there is a UMPU test for the one-sample problem: following Shao's Mathematical Statistics book, the correct UMPU test for the one sample problem of testing $H_0:\theta \in [\theta_l, \theta_u]$ vs $H_A:\theta \notin [\theta_l, \theta_u]$ for $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta, \sigma^2)$ is the test:

\begin{align*}
\delta(X) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } \bar{x} < c_1  \text{ or } \bar{x} > c_2 \\
0 & \text{if } c_1 < \bar{x} < c_2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ satisfy for a level $\alpha$ test and CDF function $\Phi$:

\begin{align*}
1 + \Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(c_1-\theta_l)}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(c_2-\theta_l)}{\sigma}\right) = \alpha \\
1 + \Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(c_1-\theta_u)}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(c_2-\theta_u)}{\sigma}\right) = \alpha \\
\end{align*}
(I believe this is correct, but I may have made a mistake)

I also know that if the null hypothesis were instead something like $H_0: \theta_1-\theta_2=0$ then this would be a great problem for welch's t-test. But here I don't know how to derive the interval UMPU test (if one even exists?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (?) I've figured out how to do this, even when the variance is unknown. At least in simulations it works.

There is not a closed form solution, but I believe the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ that are desired need to solve

\begin{align*}
&1+F_{v}\left(\frac{c_1-\theta_l}{\text{SE}}\right)-F_{v}\left(\frac{c_2-\theta_l}{\text{SE}}\right) = \alpha \\
&1+F_{v}\left(\frac{c_1-\theta_u}{\text{SE}}\right)-F_{v}\left(\frac{c_2-\theta_u}{\text{SE}}\right) =\alpha \\
\end{align*}

Where $F_v$ is the cdf of the Student's T-distribution with $v$ degrees of freedom (e.g., `pt` in R). For unbiased sample variances $s_1^2$ and $s_2^2$ and sample sizes $n_1$, $n_2$, $v$ is calculated as
\begin{align*}
v = \frac{(s_1^2/n_1+s_2^2/n_2)^2}{s_1^2/(n_1-1) + s_2^2/(n_2-1)}
\end{align*}

And $\text{SE}$ is the standard error calculated as
\begin{align*}
\text{SE}=\sqrt{s_1^2/n_1+s_2^2/n_2}
\end{align*}

The test rejects the null if $\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}$ is outside the interval $[c_1, c_2]$. I don't have the p-value calculation worked out yet.

I wrote a really, really stupid function to do this in the instance where $c_2=-c_1$ (note, the score needs to be checked to make sure the approx of $c_1$ and $c_2$ are correct enough). Obviously way faster/better/smatter ways to do this

```
umpu_2s_ttest <- function(X, inds_0, inds_1, epsilon, alpha) {
n <- length(inds_0)+length(inds_1)
n0 <- length(inds_0)
n1 <- length(inds_1)
m <- mean(X[inds_1])-mean(X[inds_0])
s02 <- var(X[inds_0])
s12 <- var(X[inds_1])

se <- sqrt(s02/n0+s12/n1)
v <- (s02/n0+s12/n1)^2 / ( (s02/n0)^2/(n0-1) + (s12/n1)^2/(n1-1) )

## First pass
best_score_i <- 1000
best_cv_i <- NULL
for(cv in seq(0,100,0.5)) {
    lower <- (-cv-epsilon) / se
    upper <- (cv-epsilon) / se
    alpha_est <- 1+pt(lower, v)-pt(upper, v)
    score <- abs(alpha_est-alpha)
    if(score<best_score_i) {
        best_score_i <- score
        best_cv_i <- cv
    }
}

## Second pass
best_score <- 1000
best_cv <- NULL
for(cv in seq(max(0, best_cv_i-0.5), best_cv_i+0.5, 0.0005)) {
    lower <- (-cv-epsilon) / se
    upper <- (cv-epsilon) / se
    alpha_est <- 1+pt(lower, v)-pt(upper, v)
    score <- abs(alpha_est-alpha)
    if(score<best_score) {
        best_score <- score
        best_cv <- cv
    }
}

return(list(sig=(m>best_cv) | (m<(-best_cv)),
                m=m, cv=best_cv, score=best_score))}
```